# Powershell - Combine two CSVs with 1 CSV Dynamic

Tags: powershell, csv

I have created a Powershell script to send alerts based on network status' found by running a Python script to check Uplink status. The Python script creates a CSV and my Powershell script selects the certain Rows and combines it with a seperate CSV that references the assigned agents.

I need guidance on how to add to the script to intelligently select the agent that is assigned to a network for example Agent 1 assigned to Network 1 and so on as previously it would simply iterate through both CSVs line by line and if any changes happen on the network the original CSV changes the network rows which is different to the agent CSV. For example Agent 1 assigned to Network 3.

I am using the following line of code to generate and combine CSVs

```
0..($csv1.Count-1) |
Select @{n='Network';e={$csv1[$_].Network}},@{n='WAN1 Status';e={$csv1[$_].'WAN1 Status'}},@{n='WAN2 Status';e={$csv1[$_].'WAN2 Status'}},@{n='Agent';e={$csv2[$_].Agent}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\Stuff\Scripts\Health Checks\csv3.csv' -NoType
```

I believe there may be a better way to do this but I am hitting many walls.

**CSV Input File 1**

```
Network,Device,Serial,MAC,Model,WAN1 Status,WAN2 Status
053 - Network 1,053-Network1-FW01,XXXX-XXXX-XXXX,00:00:00:00:00:00,MX64,Active,Not connected
067 - Network 2,067-Network2-FW01,XXXX-XXXX-XXXX,00:00:00:00:00:00,MX64,Active,Ready
075 - Network 3,075-Network3-FW01,XXXX-XXXX-XXXX,00:00:00:00:00:00,MX64,Active,Not connected
```

**CSV Input File 2**

```
Network,Agent
053 - Network 1,Agent1
067 - Network 2,Agent2
075 - Network 3,Agent3
```

I am currently having the below issue.

```
Network,WAN1 Status,WAN2 Status,Agent
053 - Network 1,Active,Not connected,Agent 1
075 - Network 3,Active,Ready,Agent 2
067 - Network 2,Active,Not connected,Agent 3
```

Notice how the Network 3 is now assigned to Agent 2, this is not desired.

**Desired CSV**

```
Network,WAN1 Status,WAN2 Status,Agent
053 - Network 1,Active,Not connected,Agent 1
075 - Network 3,Active,Ready,Agent3
067 - Network 2,Active,Not connected,Agent 2
```

Could anyone advise a better way to do this as I am open to anything.

Comment: you likely need to add sanitized versions of the two input CV files and the desired output from the two inputs.

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT - Does this explain better?

Comment: You need to add quotes to each cell, use double quotes to enclose each cell, just replace every comma with "," and ^|$ with " , then it's better to eliminate spaces in headers, use either WAN1Status or WAN1_Status, finally you can import to csv files using Import-Csv, it creates arrays of PSCustomObjects, then you can combine csv files like this: [PSCustomObject]@{Property1=$($CSV1[$_].one);Property2=...} | epcsv -notypeinformation -append

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT Hi, I did try what you suggested but the formatting was all messed up with lots of blank spaces in the csv not sure if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to look up the agent value in csv2 rather than use the same line number for both files. I don't know how large csv2 is, but the lookups will be slower.

```
Foreach ($i in 0..($csv1.Count-1)){
    Select @{n='Network';e={$csv1[$i].Network}},
        @{n='WAN1 Status';e={$csv1[$i].'WAN1 Status'}},
        @{n='WAN2 Status';e={$csv1[$i].'WAN2 Status'}},
        @{n='Agent';e={($csv2| where {$_.Network -like $csv1[$i].Network}).Agent}} |
    
    Export-Csv 'C:\Stuff\Scripts\Health Checks\csv3.csv' -NoType
}
```

This assumes `csv2.Network` values are unique